# kong Error when run it : don't know how to auth: 10

Tags: api-gateway, kong

I want to set up the [Kong API gateway](https://konghq.com/) version 2.2.1  .

I installed Postgres version 13.1. but when I want to start Kong, this error shows up  :

```
 [root@ip208 kong]# kong start -c kong.conf 
Error: don't know how to auth: 10

  Run with --v (verbose) or --vv (debug) for more details
```

I test it  with --v  :

```
[root@ip208 kong]# kong start -c kong.conf --v
2020/12/27 02:41:44 [verbose] Kong: 2.2.1
2020/12/27 02:41:44 [verbose] reading config file at kong.conf
2020/12/27 02:41:44 [verbose] prefix in use: /usr/local/kong
Error: 
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/pgmoon/init.lua:211: don't know how to auth: 10
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'auth'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/pgmoon/init.lua:211: in function 'connect'
    .../share/lua/5.1/kong/db/strategies/postgres/connector.lua:211: in function 'connect'
    .../share/lua/5.1/kong/db/strategies/postgres/connector.lua:527: in function 'query'
    .../share/lua/5.1/kong/db/strategies/postgres/connector.lua:279: in function 'init'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/init.lua:141: in function 'init_connector'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/start.lua:31: in function 'cmd_exec'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:45>
    /usr/local/bin/kong:9: in function 'file_gen'
    init_worker_by_lua:49: in function <init_worker_by_lua:47>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    init_worker_by_lua:56: in function <init_worker_by_lua:54>
```

Answer (score 0):

the auth scheme for that Postgres version is not supported by Kong, see https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/6035